# Pass to another page after successfully login

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to go to another page after login so How can I pass to another page after successfully login using Ajax and php ? when ajax send a request to php and then get the response like (if the response is ('true') or ('false') this responses depends on checking the username and password) so i do not know how to deal with this response in ajax to use it as a condition to pass to the next page. please help.

```
var HttPRequest = false;

   function doCallAjax(Mode) {

      HttPRequest = false;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
         HttPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
         if (HttPRequest.overrideMimeType) {
            HttPRequest.overrideMimeType('text/html');
         }
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
         try {
            HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         } catch (e) {
            try {
               HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {}
         }
      }

      if (!HttPRequest) {
         alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
         return false;
      }

      var url = 'PHP_Login.php';


      var pmeters = "tEmail=" + encodeURI( document.getElementById("Email").value) +
                    "&tpassword=" + encodeURI( document.getElementById("password").value ) +

                    "&tMode=" + Mode;



        HttPRequest.open('POST',url,true);


        HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", pmeters.length);
        HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        HttPRequest.send(pmeters);


        HttPRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
        {

             if(HttPRequest.readyState == 3)  // Loading Request
              {
               document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = "Now is Loading...";

              }

             if(HttPRequest.readyState == 4) // Return Request
              {
               document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = HttPRequest.responseText;
               document.getElementById("Email").value = '';
               document.getElementById("password").value = '';

           }
            }

        }
```

Comment: seems like you forgot your code?

Comment: sorry guys i cont upload my code i do not know why

Comment: copy paste is all it should take, then mark it as code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect to a different page in PHP use

```
header("Location: http://example.com/success.html");
```

Comment: thank you mate but i want to pass it  in ajax not in php

Comment: Ajax isn't a language on its own. It is a way of communicating with GET and POST requests (etc). Also what do you mean by "pass to a different page"?

Comment: okay mate, i mean to go to the page after login like manager page.